# Why does Firebase recommend installing both the library and its types as normal dependencies?

Tags: typescript, firebase

I've been reading through the Firebase documentation and I came across a section that's got me a bit puzzled. The documentation states the following:

"Type dependencies should be the same kind as the library dependency. For example, you should not save uuid as a normal dependency and @types/uuid as a dev dependency or peer dependency."
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies#additional_steps_for_typescript

I used to think that it was best to put type definitions (like @types/uuid) in devDependencies. This is because they are only used during development and when compiling TypeScript into JavaScript. After the code is compiled into JavaScript for the final product, these type definitions aren't needed anymore.

Why then does the Firebase documentation recommend installing both the library (e.g., uuid) and its type definitions (@types/uuid) as regular dependencies? Is there a particular reason behind this that I should also consider in my own project?

Thanks for your help!